# Save image from URL to a field from a custom module

Tags: 7, media

With a custom module, I'm trying to create a new node, save an image to a node's image field from URL and save the node as well. However when I'm trying to save the node, this error messages comes up

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in file_field_presave()
>   (line 220 of
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web20/web/modules/file/file.field.inc).
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$uri in file_save() (line 566 of
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web20/web/includes/file.inc).
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '' for key 'uri': INSERT INTO {file_managed} (filesize, status,
>   timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 0
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =>
>   1373886933 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7136 of
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web20/web/includes/common.inc).

This is the code I wrote for saving the image into a folder, saving it into a node field and save the node:

```
      $node = new stdClass();
      $node->type = "flickr_image";
      node_object_prepare($node);

      $node->title    = $photo['title'];
      $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

      $node->uid = 1;

      $url = $image[10]['source']; //URL of the image
      $directory = file_build_uri('flickr_images/');

      $file = system_retrieve_file($url, $directory, TRUE, $replace = FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
      file_save($file);

      $node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE] = $file;

      if($node = node_submit($node)) {
          node_save($node);
      }
```

What am I doing wrong? I've looked up several similar questions here, but I don't understand what's the problem. The messages only come up when I use node_save(). When I comment it out, the messages disappear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hope this will help  you,

In Drupal 7,  for your requirement I made some changes.

- As [system_retrieve_file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_retrieve_file/7) function will download a file from a remote source, copy it from temp to a specified destination and optionally save it to the `file_managed` table if you want it to be managed.

  `$node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = "node_type";
  node_object_prepare($node);
  $node->title    =  'your title here';
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $node->uid = 1;
  $url = 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/k1_a31af7ac.png';
  //I have used picture folder to store images using image field settings
  $file_info = system_retrieve_file($url, 'public://pictures/', TRUE);
  if($file_info->fid){
      $node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['fid'] = $file_info->fid;//assign fid
  }
  $node->field_test_field[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['value'] = 'test';//other fields 
  if($node = node_submit($node)) {
      node_save($node);
      drupal_set_message('submitted successfully');
  }`

Make changes as per your requirement.