# How to get the image from the url and store in the custom path?

Tags: 7, hooks, migrations

```
if(empty($nodevalue->field_beachesimages)){
    $imageurl=array(explode(",",$nodevalue->field_beach_migrateurlhidden[$nodevalue->language]['0']['value']));
    foreach ($imageurl as $imagechange) {
        $countimagurl=count($imagechange);
        if($countimagurl>10)
            $imgdata=9;
        else
            $imgdata=$countimagurl;
        for($i=0;$i<$imgdata;$i++){              
           $image =$imagechange[$i];
           $file = system_retrieve_file($image,'public://beachesmigration/', TRUE, $replace = FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
           echo "<pre>";print_r($file);echo "</pre>"; exit;
           file_save($file);
           file_usage_add($file, 'iks_beaches', 'beaches', $file->fid);
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: what is the problem in the above code? Are u getting any errors? Pls mention

Comment: i use the above code but no folder creation takes place :(

Comment: You can use drupal_mkdir() to create new folder in the code above Link : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/drupal_mkdir/7

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you.

In Drupal 7 , [system_retrieve_file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_retrieve_file/7) function will download a file from a remote source, copy it from temp to a specified destination and optionally save it to the file_managed table if you want it to be managed.

- You need to create a folder **beachesmigration** inside **sites\default\files**.
- By using **system_retrieve_file** it will be store your images inside **beachesmigration** folder with the filename you no need to specify the filename manually.

```
 $image = 'http://wordpress.ikitesurf.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/2032239599_fdce5e0ab0_z.jpg';
//I have used picture folder to store images using image field settings
 $file = system_retrieve_file($image, 'public://beachesmigration/', TRUE, $replace = FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

[Source](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79329/save-image-from-url-to-a-field-from-a-custom-module/79352#79352)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function savefile($filepath, $uid = 1) {
  global $base_url;
  if (filesize($filepath) == 0 ) {
    return array();
 }
  $file = (object) array(
    'uid' => $uid,
    'uri' => $filepath,
    'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($filepath),
    'status' => 1,
  );
  if(file_exists($filepath)) {
    $file = file_copy($file, 'public://');   //Change path here
    return $file;
  } else {
    return array();
  }
}



$file = savefile("http://wordpress.ikitesurf.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/2032239599_fdce5e0ab0_z.jpg");
```

Comment: Hello. Yuor answer does not mention `$pathval` or `beachesmigration`, so how it is supposed to help?